# How do I replace an XYZ coordinate system on an already available plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, eps, 3d

I have an eps file looking like this:

[image]

I have no access to the original dataset, so replotting it is not an option. I would like to replace the ugly 80s style coordinate system (Both the captions and the lines) with a coordinate system generated by `pgfplots`. I have seen somewhere that this is possible, but I don't remember where and how. I can remove the captions and lines with Illustrator so that I only have the plot.

Could someone please point me to a source where it's explained how to achieve this?

---

I got it to run with example data from the PGFPLOTS manual. However, when I enter my coordinates:

```
(0,0,0) => (36.5,64.6-64.6)
(0,10,0) => (0,64.6-36.5)
(10,0,0) => (93.4,64.6-47.8)
(5,5,1) => (44.3,64.6-40.6)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error: Sorry, 'scale uniformly' failed bec
ause its actual implementation works only if y_x = 0 (for 2d axes) or if z_x = 
0 (for 3d axes). The result will not fill the prescribed dimensions. For 2d axe
s, you may also want to consider the 'unit vector ratio' key.
```

What is it trying to tell me? I don't understand this error message.

---

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

%%%<
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}
%%%>

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    grid=both,minor tick num=1,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,zlabel=Local Dose
    ]
\addplot3 graphics[
    points={%  important
        (0,1,0) => (0,207-112)
        (1,0,0) => (446,207-133)
        (0.5546,0.5042,1.825) => (236,207)
        (0,0,0) => (194,207-202)
    }] {data.png};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's the syntax `\addplot3 graphics....`. An example : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78855/problem-with-external-graphics-and-3d-pgfplots See the manual for that usage.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), otherwise this is hard to guess which options you used. In principle your complete use case is in detail described in the pgfplots manual from p. 46 on.

Comment: Have you can checked the inside of the eps-file? 
There might be a small chance that the elevation matrix is still available in readable form inside it, if the plot was built as a postscript program.

Comment: @g.kov Not the case... :(

Comment: If you open the `.log` file of your example, you will see the axis parameters that fitted your `points` argument. In your case, `z={(-2.4000000000,1.54999000000000)}` which appears to be wrong. And that is what the error message tries to tell you: the x component of the z vector is non-zero. I fear that somehow, the input points are not what you wanted.

Comment: when I try to reproduce your MWE, I get an axis which appears to be correct (and no error message), except that the image, the relative angles of the axis vectors, and the tick labels appear to be unrelated to your original eps image. Is that intentional?