# Import external eps into pgfplot

Tags: graphics, pgfplots, eps

I have some flow image files in `.eps` format which I would like to import in pgfplots. What is the practical way to do so?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103899/how-do-i-replace-an-xyz-coordinate-system-on-an-already-available-plot

Comment: I will try this

Comment: So what do you want to do with pgfplots? Do you have the data or the image without any coordinates overlayed ?

Comment: I just have an image without any coordinates

Comment: So it's similar to the linked question then. This is covered in the [`pgfplots` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) Section 4.2.7. You can start from there and update your question if it doesn't go through with the step you are stuck with.