# Is it possible to extrude a curve surface (add a thickness to surface)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents*}{filename.txt}
    0 0 1.36
    1 0 1.50
    2 0 1.60
    3 0 1.69
    4 0 1.77
    5 0 1.80
    6 0 1.76
    7 0 1.68
    8 0 1.58
    9 0 1.41
    10 0 1.24

    0 1 1.46
    1 1 1.60
    2 1 1.73
    3 1 1.83
    4 1 1.92
    5 1 1.97
    6 1 1.95
    7 1 1.86
    8 1 1.73
    9 1 1.55
    10 1 1.37

    0 2 1.54
    1 2 1.69
    2 2 1.84
    3 2 1.97
    4 2 2.07
    5 2 2.12
    6 2 2.11
    7 2 2.02
    8 2 1.87
    9 2 1.68
    10 2 1.49

    0 3 1.56
    1 3 1.74
    2 3 1.92
    3 3 2.07
    4 3 2.18
    5 3 2.25
    6 3 2.24
    7 3 2.14
    8 3 1.99
    9 3 1.80
    10 3 1.59

    0 4 1.56
    1 4 1.74
    2 4 1.96
    3 4 2.13
    4 4 2.25
    5 4 2.32
    6 4 2.31
    7 4 2.22
    8 4 2.07
    9 4 1.86
    10 4 1.63

    0 5 1.56
    1 5 1.74
    2 5 1.95
    3 5 2.14
    4 5 2.27
    5 5 2.34
    6 5 2.33
    7 5 2.24
    8 5 2.09
    9 5 1.88
    10 5 1.64

    0 6 1.52
    1 6 1.71
    2 6 1.92
    3 6 2.09
    4 6 2.22
    5 6 2.29
    6 6 2.28
    7 6 2.20
    8 6 2.06
    9 6 1.87
    10 6 1.65

    0 7 1.45
    1 7 1.66
    2 7 1.85
    3 7 2.00
    4 7 2.11
    5 7 2.18
    6 7 2.18
    7 7 2.11
    8 7 1.98
    9 7 1.80
    10 7 1.61

    0 8 1.37
    1 8 1.56
    2 8 1.73
    3 8 1.87
    4 8 1.97
    5 8 2.04
    6 8 2.04
    7 8 1.98
    8 8 1.87
    9 8 1.71
    10 8 1.55

    0 9 1.29
    1 9 1.41
    2 9 1.57
    3 9 1.72
    4 9 1.82
    5 9 1.87
    6 9 1.87
    7 9 1.83
    8 9 1.74
    9 9 1.62
    10 9 1.47

    0 10 1.17
    1 10 1.25
    2 10 1.41
    3 10 1.55
    4 10 1.65
    5 10 1.70
    6 10 1.70
    7 10 1.66
    8 10 1.58
    9 10 1.48
    10 10 1.34
    \end{filecontents*}

    \begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[view={-20}{20}, grid=both, xmin=0, ymin=0, zmin=0]

          \clip[
              rounded corners=5,
              x=1.1cm,y=.4cm,z=3cm,
              yshift=.1cm, xshift=-.7cm
          ]
              (.3,2) -- (0,1) -- (.5,.3) -- (1,.2) -- (2,1.3) -- (3.5,.5) --
              (4.5,2) -- (3.5,3) -- (1.5,3.4) -- (1.5,2.5) --
              cycle
              [yshift=2.7cm]
              (.3,2) -- (0,1) -- (.5,.3) -- (1,.2) -- (2,1.3) -- (3.5,.5) --
              (4.5,2)
              [rounded corners=0]
              parabola[parabola height=1.1cm] cycle
          ;

          \addplot3[surf] file {filename.txt};

        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Related but unanswered: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327393/how-can-i-add-thickness-to-a-3d-surface-plot