# Computing color for a mesh using the parametric coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmathparse

**Question:** Is there a way to use the *parametric parameters* (instead of the absolute `x` and `y`) inside the `mathparse` used to calculate the color of a `surf`?

**Motivation:** The function I have to plot has a very difficult inverse, so this is not an option.

**Code example:**
The code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[view={0}{90},domain=0:1,shader=interp,
            mesh/color input=explicit mathparse]
            \addplot3 [surf, point meta={symbolic={Hsb=x,y,1}}]
                      (x,y,1);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

while if I would plot `(x,y*.5+.5,1)` instead of `(x,y,1)`, I would get

[image]

I would like the color to depend on the original `x` and `y`, and not on `x` and `y*.5+.5`.

Hopefully anybody understands my question. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can make the value of x and y dynamic. In the sense that somewhere else you have a function that calculates the value of x and y. For a very low-level way, have a look at pgf keys, section 82 in the manual: http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf  However I think there are probably easier out-of-the-box solutions.

Comment: @Huang_d, thank you. I have absolutely no idea how to do this, but I guess you mean something like first
`loop u: loop v: mypgfkey(x(u,v),y(u,v)) = (u,v);`
and then plot with
`point meta={symbolic={Hsb=myhue(mypgfkeyuv(x,y)),mysat(mypgfkeyuv(x,y)),1}}`. Right?

Comment: I just know it exists :-/. It is one option. If you have the time, read through some of the areas that are dedicated to defining a function and the parts that define the `[surf]` option in the pgfplots manual. Ideally it is well-documented. It's not super difficult but it needs at least two afternoons, depending on your background.

Comment: Did you try `Hsb={\x,\y,1}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out `\x` stores the original *parametric parameters*. This is not documented (as far as I can tell). So this trick might break in the future.

I hope the following complicated example proves my point: the tangent points of tori are of different color. Hence the color is not a function of its position.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{X}{0}{%
    \pgfmathparse{
        y<121?
            cos(x)*(3+cos(3*y))
            :
            (y<139?
                inf
                :
                (y<261?
                    4+cos(x)*(3+cos(3*y))
                    :
                    (y<279?
                        inf
                        :
                        8+cos(x)*(3+cos(3*y))
                    )
                )
            )
    }%
}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Y}{0}{%
    \pgfmathparse{
        y<121?
            sin(x)*(3+cos(3*y))
            :
            (y<139?
                inf
                :
                (y<261?
                    sin(3*y)
                    :
                    (y<279?
                        inf
                        :
                        sin(x)*(3+cos(3*y))
                    )
                )
            )
    }%
}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{Z}{0}{%
    \pgfmathparse{
        y<121?
            sin(3*y)
            :
            (y<139?
                inf
                :
                (y<261?
                    sin(x)*(3+cos(3*y))
                    :
                    (y<279?
                        inf
                        :
                        sin(3*y)
                    )
                )
            )
    }%
}

\tikz[cap=round,join=round]{
    \begin{axis}[axis equal,
                 %shader=interp,
                 mesh/color input=explicit mathparse]
        \addplot3[surf,unbounded coords=jump,
                  domain  =0:360,samples  =27,
                  domain y=0:400,samples y=41,
                  z buffer=sort,
                  point meta={symbolic={Hsb=\x,.5+cos(3*\y)/3,1}}]
            (X,Y,Z);
    \end{axis}
}
```

Example is taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365790/51022. Your question is exactly what I wanted to ask when I was writing that answer.

Comment: Wow thank you very much! This is also a beautiful example!